# Toast Message in Multiple lines

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is there a way we can show the toast message in multiple lines?

```
 resultsToast.setParams({                
                title : 'IWS Cannot be created',
                message: 'Cant create new Internship Work Sites for past cohorts. \
Cohort End Date: '+ opp.Cohort_Sem__r.End_date__c,                                
                duration:' 5000',
                key: 'info_alt',
                type: 'error', 
                mode: 'sticky'
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried `\n`?

Comment: I tried, I am getting the error while saving "Unterminated string [23, 26]: 'Cant create new Internship Work Sites for past cohorts. \n': Source"

Comment: This was already asked here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195129/show-lightning-toast-message-in-multiple-lines

Comment: Yes, tried that no luck:( should we merge this with the above question?