# How to set the width of Toast message box in lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, toast

I have a requirement where field value from long text field called Alert_Text_Timeline__c will be displayed as toast message on click of a button.

Below is my code

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Map" default="{}" />
    <aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <force:recordData targetFields="{!v.record}"
        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        recordUpdated="{!c.recordLoaded}"
        fields="Alert_Text_Timeline__c" />
    <div>
        <lightning:card>
   &nbsp;&nbsp; <strong><b> Important Alert: </b></strong>  <lightning:button label="Please click here"
                          variant="brand"
                          disabled="{!v.disabled}" 
                          onclick="{!c.showInfo}"/></lightning:card>
        
    </div> 
</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
({
    recordLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.disabled", false);
    },
    showInfo : function(component, event, helper) {
        var record = component.get("v.record");
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            
            message: record.Alert_Text_Timeline__c,
            duration:' 5000',
            key: 'info_alt',
            type: 'info',
            mode: 'dismissible'           
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Now, I have the text in long text field stored as line by line but when it is rendered as toast message, I'm getting it in a single line.

Is there any way I can display text in toast message line after line or adjust width of toast box so that it will be displayed line after line.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the method I used in my component to get line breaks in toast message

```
<aura:html tag="style">.toastMessage.forceActionsText{white-space : pre-line !important;}</aura:html>
```

Original comment can be found [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/303277/84228).